# How to apply a visit names to subject IDs using data from two tables

Tags: r

I have two tables the first is a single column with Subject Ids and the second is a single column with the Visit Names

```
library(tibble)

subjects <- tibble("Subject Id" = c("1-1", "1-2", "1-3"))

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  `Subject Id`
  <chr>       
1 1-1         
2 1-2         
3 1-3)
                   
visits <- tibble("Visits" = c("a", "b", "c"))

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  Visits
  <chr> 
1 a     
2 b     
3 c
```

And I want to create a table that looks like this so I see every potential visit for every subject.

| Subject ID | Visits |
| --- | --- |
| 1-1 | a |
| 1-1 | b |
| 1-1 | c |
| 1-2 | a |
| 1-2 | b |
| 1-2 | c |

I've been trying to find a good solution, but all of the similar questions I find go back to doing a merge and that doesn't seem like the correct solution for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(subjects, visits)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  `Subject Id` Visits
  <chr>        <chr> 
1 1-1          a     
2 1-1          b     
3 1-1          c     
4 1-2          a     
5 1-2          b     
6 1-2          c     
7 1-3          a     
8 1-3          b     
9 1-3          c
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
 expand.grid(c(subjects, visits))
  Subject Id Visits
1        1-1      a
2        1-2      a
3        1-3      a
4        1-1      b
5        1-2      b
6        1-3      b
7        1-1      c
8        1-2      c
9        1-3      c
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
merge(subjects, visits, by = NULL)

  Subject.Id Visits
1        1-1      a
2        1-2      a
3        1-3      a
4        1-1      b
5        1-2      b
6        1-3      b
7        1-1      c
8        1-2      c
9        1-3      c
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R, you can do an `outer` join

```
merge(subjects, visits)
  Subject Id Visits
1        1-1      a
2        1-2      a
3        1-3      a
4        1-1      b
5        1-2      b
6        1-3      b
7        1-1      c
8        1-2      c
9        1-3      c
```

if you need it in the ordering of `ID`:

```
rev(merge(visits, subjects))
  Subject Id Visits
1        1-1      a
2        1-1      b
3        1-1      c
4        1-2      a
5        1-2      b
6        1-2      c
7        1-3      a
8        1-3      b
9        1-3      c
```

Answer (score 0):

using `cross_join()` from package `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
cross_join(subjects,visits)

  `Subject Id` Visits
  <chr>        <chr> 
    1-1          a     
    1-1          b     
    1-1          c     
    1-2          a     
    1-2          b     
    1-2          c     
    1-3          a     
    1-3          b     
    1-3          c
```